# Валидация поля формы по данным валидации поля node

Tags: php, api, form, drupal

При создании числового поля в материале я указываю мин. и  макс. значение этого поля.

На странице посредством Form API я вывожу пошаговую форму. В это форме я хочу проверить значение поля, что оно в диапозоне мин. и  макс. Как произвести валидацию?

Answer (score 1):

Функциями `field_info_instance()` и `field_info_instances()` получил нужные мне данные